# DataTables warning: table id=tbdata - Requested unknown parameter 'CodLocalidad' for row 0, column 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

[image]

I have a service that delivers the following array of objects, but when using the datable.js component it always throws the following error:

Error Message:
DataTables warning: table id=tbdata - Requested unknown parameter 'CodLocalidad' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

My code:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
           tablaData = $('#tbdata').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            "ajax": {
                "url": '/Localidad/Lista',
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "CodLocalidad",  "visible": false, "searchable": false},
                { "data": "Descripcion"},
                { "data": "CodPuntoVenta"},
                { "data": "SituacionRegistro" } ,

                {
                    "defaultContent": '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-editar btn-sm mr-2"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>' +
                        '<button class="btn btn-danger btn-eliminar btn-sm"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button>',
                    "orderable": false,
                    "searchable": false,
                    "width": "150px"
                }
            ],
            order: [[0, "desc"]],
            dom: '<"row"<"col-sm-4"><"col-sm-4 text-center">>t<"row"<"col-sm-4"><"col-sm-4 text-center"p>>',
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Exportar Excel',
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    title: '',
                    filename: 'Reporte Categorias',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: [1, 2]
                    }
                }, 'pageLength'
            ],
            language: {
                url: "https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.11.5/i18n/es-ES.json"
            }
           });
```

});

Comment: You show that you're checking for the data on the server side. Have you verified that the AJAX call for the datatable is successful? The error suggests it's not, or there is a problem with the format of the data returned from the AJAX call.  Can you update your question and add in an example of what the data returned by AJAX looks like?

Comment: Also, the error you posted has a link to details about the error.  Have you gone through the various factors listed under the Resolution section of that page and verified those aspects of your code?

Comment: And, it is sometimes helpful to comment out various settings in your datatable definition in order to see if any particular setting is triggering the error. So, for example, make a simple datatable using your AJAX datasource. If that works, you can start adding in other settings one by one to see which one is causing the problem. If it doesn't work, you can keep troubleshooting the simple example

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. YES in the link on the page there is not much information. In the image you can verify that the data return is successful, but for some reason it cannot read it. I think it is because it is an array of objects, in any case I don't know how I should place the columns of data so that they can be read.

Comment: Your AJAX is expecting a json result, not an array: `"datatype": "json"`. Have you tried converting your array to json before it is returned from server side?